# Sync feature branch with master without rebase?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, feature-branch

At work we develop on top of a feature branch model where all integrations end up in the `master` branch eventually. We branch from `master` and **merge** to `master`. This results in a very complex history graph and we are looking at ways to simplify our development workflow.

One way of doing so it to **rebase** instead of **merge**. However, we have an internal GitLab instance installed where overwrite permissions are disabled (and they are not going to be enabled for our project only). As such **rebase** is out of the question.

I honestly don't see any way around this. But I'm no Git expert and I might be missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about creating a new branch on the newest master, and applying all commits from the feature branch on top of the new branch. This creates a new branch that is a rebased on top of master

Comment: I guess that's a sensible solution @BartlomiejLewandowski.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT - my first answer was by no means the best way, although it would work. I've left it below in case it interests anyone. A better answer is the following:**

You can use [git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) with a range of commits to apply the `featurebranch` commits one at a time to `master`. Any commit range spec will do, but in your case the easiest is probably (with master checked out):

```
git cherry-pick featurebranch ^master
```

which means 'cherry-pick everything on featurebranch that isn't on master'.

**Old, poor solution**

You could use [git format-patch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [git am](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am).

While on branch `featurebranch`, running `git format-patch master` will generate a patch file for each commit on `featurebranch` that's not on `master`. You can then switch to `master` and apply the patches with `git am`.

(In the more straightforward case where `featurebranch` hasn't been shared with anyone, then rather than rebasing `master` against `featurebranch`, you can instead rebase `featurebranch` against `master`, which will make `featurebranch` a copy of `master` with extra commits on top, and then rebase `master` against `featurebranch`, which will make git fast-forward `master`.)

Comment: I think this is too confusing and too much overhead.

Comment: I've realized there's a vastly easier way, I've edited my answer to include it.